# Can I push to both "origin" and "alt" in one command?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

To commit my project update to both GitHub and BitBucket, I have to do:

```
git commit -am message
git push
git push alt
```

can I do both pushes in one command?

Sometimes I even have to push to more than two remote repos. Something like `push all` maybe?

Comment: If you're talking about multiple remotes, note that the conventional name for the default remote is `origin`, not `master` - which is the conventional name for the default *branch*

Comment: Your write: *can I merge both pushes in one command?* Be careful with the term "merge"; it has a very precise meaning in Git. Do you mean "do both pushes in one command"?